# Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, string, int

I am getting the error message Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'Int'

I have browsed through other questions like this but it still shows the error.

```
 if sunscreenName.text != nil && reapplyTime.text != nil {
     sunscreen = sunscreenName.text!
     reApplyTime = reapplyTime.text

     //Some sort of message such as Progress hud
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line has the error?  Presumably `reApplyTime` is an `Int` and not a `String?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got your problem, actually what happens here Swift is is **type safe langauge**

So what you are doing is is to store a `String`  value in `Int` which will not happen automatically you need to convert it to **Int**

like this
`Int(sunscreenName.text)`

**But there is a catch there not all string are convertible to Int type, fo  e.g.**

```
let name = "roshan"
```

if you try to convert it to  `Int` it will give you a nil

`let a = Int(name)`

So its better you do a **optional Binding here provided by Swift**

```
if let sunValue = Int(sunscreenName.text),let reApplyValue = Int(reapplyTime.text) {
 sunscreen = sunValue
 reApplyTime = reApplyValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading through [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) to get a better understanding of Swift and its fundamental concepts, since this question is fairly basic.

You make several mistakes:

```
if sunscreenName.text != nil && reapplyTime.text != nil {
```

This is wrong. In Swift, if you plan to use the value later, you should use `if let` rather than comparing to `nil`. Comparing to `nil` leaves the values optional, but `if let` unwraps them. So, do this instead:

```
if let sunscreenText = sunscreenName.text, let reapplyText = reapplyTime.text {
```

Now you have the `sunscreenText` and `reapplyText` variables, which are typed `String`, not `String?` (i.e. they are not optional).

Now, there's these two lines.

```
sunscreen = sunscreenName.text!
reApplyTime = reapplyTime.text
```

You don't say which one is giving the error, but the issue is the same in either case. First, use our unwrapped `sunscreenText` and `reapplyText` variables instead of `sunscreenName.text!` and `reapplyTime.text`. Next, if one of these is meant to be an `Int` instead of a `String`, cast it. Swift is not like JavaScript, in that it won't automatically convert values from one type to another, so if something is a string and we need an integer, we have to convert it ourselves.

(assuming `reapplyTime` was the line that was giving the error:)

```
if let reapplyInt = Int(reapplyText) {
    reapplyTime = reapplyInt
}
```

The reason we have to unwrap is because `Int(String)` can return `nil` if the string is something that can't be converted to an integer. Alternately, we could just provide a default value:

```
reapplyTime = Int(reapplyText) ?? 0 // sets to 0 if it can't parse the string as an integer
```